# Load more feature in a youtube thumbnail gallery

Tags: javascript, youtube

Any ideas why the 'load more' feature won't load here: http://jsfiddle.net/wCKKU/54/ the way it does here: http://jsfiddle.net/qjxYN/38/? The same code is being used in each:

```
function createNextButton(getNextButton, videoListId) {
    $('<input type="button" value="Load More" id="next">').appendTo('#youvid-pager');
    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        currIndex += maxVideoResults;
        if (getNextButton == "uploadSection") {getUploads();}
        else if (getNextButton == "playlistSection") {getPlaylistVideos(videoListId);}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the id `"#youvid-pager"` but it should be `"#youmax-pager"`

```
$('<input type="button" value="Load More" id="next">').appendTo('#youmax-pager');
```

I spent too much time on that. lol.

Inserting this at line **23**:

```
if (null == maxVideoResults || maxVideoResults == "" || 
    maxVideoResults == "undefined") var maxVideoResults = 25;
```

At the end of line **165**, add `max-results` and `start-index` to the `apiUploadUrl`:

```
var apiUploadURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" 
    + youmaxUser + "/uploads/?v=2&alt=jsonc" 
    + "&max-results=" + maxVideoResults + "&start-index="+currIndex; // this is the line
```

To make the previous videos clear (and make it look like a page-refresh), do the following:
Move the the function `showUploads` which is approximately line **317**. **Uncomment** the following line:

```
    $('#youmax-video-list-div').empty();
```

This clears the previous videos

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You're my hero, you have no idea. A maddening relief it was a simple oversight like that. I really appreciate your time! Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/wCKKU/58/

Comment: Update: visual fix, but it's still not functional. Stumped.

Comment: if I run it in jsfiddle, it loads more videos but they are the same videos. is this the same for you?

Comment: Thought the load button wasn't functioning on click, but maybe that's what's happening..

Comment: okay @emily I've updated my answer. and I think it loads new videos now.

Comment: It's supposed to redirect to a new page to load the next set. I might have left that code out. Trying to combine those two codes has been really tricky because of the lightbox function, at least tricky for me!

Comment: alright. in my most recent solution, it doesn't reload, but it does put more videos at the bottom of the page when the user clicks the load button. Maybe a tool like this would help you: [text-compare](http://text-compare.com)

Comment: Thanks, great tool. This is actually the function I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/qjxYN/29/ At some point I took out code thinking it was interfering with the lightbox function. Need to track it down.

Comment: @emily i got it to reload. Uncomment that line that I have in my answer. $('#youmax-video-list-div').empty();

Comment: in the link you just sent, the line I'm talking about is 332